# quasar [vuex] unknown action type: loadUsers

Tags: vue.js, axios, quarkus, quasar

I like to get a store running to get a api call, Ive tryed a lot of examples end all ends up with

```
[vuex] unknown action type: loadUsers
```

thats my store:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";

Vue.use(Vuex);

axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    users: [],
  },
  actions: {
    loadUsers({ commit }) {
      Vue.axios.get("users").then((result) => {
        commit("SAVE_USERS", result.data);
      }).catch((error) => {
        throw new Error(`API ${error}`);
      });
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    SAVE_USERS(state, users) {
      state.users = users;
    },
  },
});
```

and thats my component to display the received data

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <table class="users">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "storenews",
  computed: mapState(["users"]),
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("loadUsers");
  },
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
table {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

taken from a working fiddle from [this codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/example-api-call-from-vuex-t7zxw)

Is this because of the Quasar Framework that I miss some fancy special stuff?

Thank you

Comment: Where you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to call your `dispatch` like this:

```
this.$store.dispatch('loadUsers', null, {root:true})
```

?

Comment: same result `[vuex] unknown action type: loadUsers`